# Makefile: Combine several targets with the same prefix into a single target

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a `makefile` with multiple targets named with the same prefix as follows:

```
STR_COMPRESS_SRCS:=string_compress.cpp
UTEST_UTIL_SRCS:=string_parser.cpp

UTEST_COM_SRCS:=utest_main.cpp \
                $(UTEST_UTIL_SRCS) \
                $(STR_COMPRESS_SRCS)
UTEST_COM_OBJS=$(UTEST_COM_SRCS:.cpp=.o)

UTEST_FLAGS=-DUNIT_TEST -DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=0

UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_SRCS:=ServerQuerier.cpp \
                           ServerQuerierTest.cpp
UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_OBJS:=$(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_SRCS:.cpp=.o)
UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_NAME:=utest_serverquerier

UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_SRCS:=ServerProtocol.cpp \
                         ServerProtocolTest.cpp
UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_OBJS:=$(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_SRCS:.cpp=.o)
UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_NAME:=utest_serverprotocol


%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x -c $< -o $@ $(INC) $(UTEST_FLAGS)

utest_all: utest_serverquerier utest_serverprotocol

utest_serverquerier: $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x $(CXXFLAGS) $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_OBJS) -o $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_NAME) -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -L. $(LIB)

utest_serverprotocol: $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x $(CXXFLAGS) $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_OBJS) -o $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_NAME) -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -L. $(LIB)

clean:
    -@rm *.o utest_*
```

Now I would like to make a single target called `utest_all` so that when I type `make utest_all` then all targets `utest_*` will be built generating multiple output files with the same names as targets.

Note: There can be many `utest_*`.

**Updated:**

- Added `utest_all`
- Added `UTEST_XXX_NAME`

When I type `make utest_all` then `make` will help build all targets specified as dependencies of `utest_all`. But the thing is, if I add unit tests for a new class (e.g. `QuerierManagerTest.cpp` then I will have to do three things below:

- Define variables that specify: source files (e.g. `UTEST_QUERIER_MANAGER_SRCS`), objects (e,g. `UTEST_QUERIER_MANAGER_OBJS`, outputs (`UTEST_QUERIER_MANAGER_NAME`).
- Add target and rule for the target, e.g. `utest_queriermanager: # blah blah...`.
- Add target `utest_queriermanager` as a dependency of `utest_all`.

By looking somehow to re-define `utest_all`. I would like to neglect the two later steps so that if I add unit tests for a new class I just need to do the only first step. In short, I want to automate the second step and third step (or even remove them if not needed, somehow).

Comment: `utest_all: utest_class_1 utest_class_2 utest_class_3`?

Comment: @melpomene I know this already, but please note that there may exist many `utest_class_*`.

Comment: I know? That's why I added them all as prerequisites.

Comment: I am looking for something like wildcard or regex, e.g. `utest_all: utest_class_*`

Comment: How would that work with variables like `$(UTEST_CLASS_3_OBJS)`? Does your makefile define those variables dynamically?

Comment: Currently I add those things manually, but looking for some way to make some rule for them.

Comment: Gives us some more details. From which source files could we deduce the `utest_class_*`? Are there, for instance, `utest_class_*.c`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Added more details. Currently once I add unit tests for a new class I manually add one more target in the `makefile`, `utest_newclass` for an instance.

Comment: You're asking make to guess which `utest_*` must be built, right? You do not want to give the list yourself, as indicates your answer to melpomene. You really want make to discover this list. Fine. But can you please explain us how make could possibly guess that one of your targets is, for instance, `utest_serverquerier`. From what you show, this name is completely arbitrary. It is **your** decision, a name that you invented. How do you think make should guess this (apart using telepathy, of course, it is not yet implemented)?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet updated the question.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you change upper case to lower case (as `ServerQuerierTest.cpp` to `utest_serverquerier`)? The solution is simpler if you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we must remove some redundancy from this makefile.

**Step 1:** use the variables we've already defined for the target names.

```
$(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_NAME): $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x $(CXXFLAGS) $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_OBJS) -o $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_NAME) -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -L. $(LIB)

$(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_NAME): $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x $(CXXFLAGS) $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_OBJS) -o $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_NAME) -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -L. $(LIB)
```

**Step 2:** use some [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), like the ones we already use in the `%.o` rule.

```
$(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_NAME): $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -L. $(LIB)

$(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_NAME): $(UTEST_COM_OBJS) $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -L. $(LIB)
```

**Step 3:** notice that these two rules have exactly the same command, and consolidate them.

```
UTESTS := $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_NAME) $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_NAME)

$(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_NAME): $(UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_OBJS)

$(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_NAME): $(UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_OBJS)

$(UTESTS): $(UTEST_COM_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -L. $(LIB)
```

Now to look at how we construct these variables.

**Step 4:** The existing makefile uses source files with upper case letters in their names (such as `ServerQuerierTest.cpp`) to build executables with names in lower case (such as `utest_serverquerier`). We could do this automatically, but I will take the liberty of preserving case in the executables' names (such as `utest_ServerQuerier`), for a simpler solution.

```
UTEST_SERVER_QUERIER_NAME := utest_ServerQuerier

UTEST_SERVER_PROTO_NAME := utest_ServerProtocol
```

**Step 5:** Now we can reduce each name to its essence:

```
CLASSES := ServerQuerier ServerProtocol

UTESTS := $(addprefix utest_, $(CLASSES))
```

**Step 6:** Now look at the rules.

```
utest_ServerQuerier: ServerQuerier.o ServerQuerierTest.o   

utest_ServerProtocol: ServerProtocol.o ServerProtocolTest.o
```

The pattern is obvious, so we can fold these rules right into the pattern rule:

```
$(UTESTS): utest_%: %.o %Test.o $(UTEST_COM_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -std=c++0x $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -L. $(LIB)
```

**So we no longer have to write new rules for new classes, all we have to do is add their names to `CLASSES`.**

*But maybe we don't even have to do that.*

**Step 7:** There seems to be a simple pattern here: the class `Foo` should be in the list if and only if the files `Foo.cpp` and `FooTest.cpp` exist. And we can presume that `FooTest.cpp` will not exist without `Foo.cpp`. So if this is correct, we can *eliminate all three manual steps and automate everything* by having Make deduce the list of tests.

```
TESTFILES := $(wildcard *Test.cpp)
CLASSES := $(patsubst %Test.cpp, %, $(TESTFILES))
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation. The main lesson is probably in your last remarks: make needs patterns. So, make beginners, if you do not have patterns, create them by renaming your files and directories, instead of trying to tweak make. And if have them already, use them.